# LocationAwareLogger exception when spring integration dependencies added to project

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-batch, slf4j, spring-integration

When I include `spring-batch-integration`, `spring-integration-file`, and `spring-integration-sftp` it results with LocationAwareLogger exception. When I remove it, everything is fine. Also having these exact dependencies in a Maven project works fine for me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:523)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:237) `spring-integration-sftp`
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

It's error out at this line:

```
final AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                        "classpath:spring/batch/config/context.xml",
                        "classpath:spring/batch/config/spring-batch.xml",
                        "classpath:spring/batch/config/spring-integration.xml");
```

My dependencies are:

```
versions += [

        mavenWagonHttp: "2.2",
        kohlsCodingStandards: "2.0.15",
        log4j:"1.2.16",
        spring:"3.2.2.RELEASE",
        springBatch:"2.2.0.RELEASE",
        springBatchIntegration:"1.2.2.RELEASE",
        springIntegrationFile:"2.1.0.RELEASE",
        springIntegrationSFTP:"2.1.0.RELEASE",
        mysqlDriver:"5.1.25",
        junit:"4.11",
        commonsConfiguration:"1.6",
        apacheCommonsLang3:"3.3.2",
        slf4jLog4j12:"1.5.6"
]

libs += [
        mavenWagonHttp: "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:$versions.mavenWagonHttp",
        kohlsCodingStandards: "com.kohls.services:services-coding-standards:$versions.kohlsCodingStandards",
        log4j:"log4j:log4j:$versions.log4j",
        spring:"org.springframework:spring-core:$versions.spring",
        springBatch:"org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:$versions.springBatch",
        springBatchInfrastructure:"org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:$versions.springBatch",
        springBatchIntegration:"org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:$versions.springBatchIntegration",
        springIntegrationFile:"org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:$versions.springIntegrationFile",
        springIntegrationSFTP:"org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:$versions.springIntegrationSFTP",
        springBatchTest:"org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:$versions.springBatch",
        junit:"junit:junit:$versions.junit",
        log4j:"log4j:log4j:$versions.log4j",
        commonsConfiguration:"commons-configuration:commons-configuration:$versions.commonsConfiguration",
        apacheCommonsLang3:"org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$versions.apacheCommonsLang3",
        slf4jLog4j12:"org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$versions.slf4jLog4j12"
]

dependencies {
    compile([
            libs.mavenWagonHttp,
            libs.kohlsCodingStandards,
            libs.log4j,
            libs.spring,
            libs.springBatch,
            libs.springBatchInfrastructure,
            libs.springBatchIntegration,
            libs.springIntegrationFile,
            libs.springIntegrationSFTP,
            libs.springBatchTest,
            libs.junit,
            libs.commonsConfiguration,
            libs.apacheCommonsLang3,
            libs.slf4jLog4j12
    ])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: How does it work without `slf4j`, just with `log4j` ?

Comment: I get the same error, but this time I also get the message `The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]` I noticed that in my external libraries I have `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`. I refreshed the Gradle project to relink all the dependencies I also removed `libs.slf4jLog4j12` from my dependencies. I don't know where these two jars are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with. I forced slf4j to use version 1.5.8 and it seems to work. If there is another way to do it let me know, otherwise I'll mark this as the best answer by tomorrow.

I added this to `build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.5.8','org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what is an issue to specify those `slf` artifacts as dependencies and both with appropriate versions...